# If $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 100$ and $(2x + 3y)^2 = 150$, then why is the value of $6xy = 25$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 100$ and $(2x + 3y)^2 = 150$

I've converted $(2x + 3y)^2 = 150$ to be

$$ 2x^2 + 12xy + 3y^2 = 150$$

Which I can then convert to

$$ 12xy = 150 - 2x^2 - 3y^2$$

I'm pretty sure I then just need to convert $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 100$ into the form of $2x^2 - 3y^2 = \text{?}$, but I'm not sure how you can, because I don't think you can just take the square root of $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 100$.

Comment: When you expand $(2x+3y)^2$ you should get $4x^2 + 12xy+9y^2$, not $2x^2 + 12xy+3y^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You converted (expanded) $(2x+3y)^2$ wrong.  It should be $$4x^2 + 12xy + 9y^2.$$  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Dagnabbit! Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just multiply things out and use what you know.

$$ 150 =(2x+3y)^2 = 4x^2 + 9y^2 + 12xy = 100 + 12xy.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$4{ x }^{ 2 }+9{ y }^{ 2 }=100\\ { \left( 2x+3y \right)  }^{ 2 }=150\Rightarrow \quad 4{ x }^{ 2 }+12xy+9{ y }^{ 2 }=150\Rightarrow 100+12xy=150\Rightarrow 6xy=25$$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding $(2x + 3y)^2 = 150$, you get
$$ 4x^2 + 12xy + 9y^2 = 150.$$

Then subtracting the other equation, you have that:

$$4x^2 + 12xy + 9y^2 - (4x^2 + 9y^2) = 150 - 100$$
that is

$$12xy = 50.$$

Then $xy = \frac{50}{12} = \frac{25}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ ab\, =\, \dfrac{1}2 \bigg[\underbrace{(a\!+\!b)^2}_{\large 150}\! -\underbrace{(a^2\!+\!b^2)}_{\large 100}\bigg].\ $ You have $\,a,b = 2x, 3y\ $